# Cannot read property 'function' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I am trying to call a function from another function in my React app. But I keep this error: `Error in login TypeError: Cannot read property 'loadDashboard' of undefined`. I searched for similar cases all I could find was (1) That I have to use `this` keyword (2) I have to mention the function inside `constructor`. I have done both then why I keep getting the error??
My code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import '../App.css';
var axios = require('axios');

class Login extends Component {
  constructor(){
    super();
    this.loadDashboard = this.loadDashboard.bind(this);
  }

  loadDashboard(token){
    axios({
      method:'get',
      url:'http://localhost:3000/api/dashboard',
      data: {
        Authorization: token
      },
      responseType:'stream'
    })
     .then(function (response) {
       console.log(response);
     })
     .catch(function (error) {
       console.log("Error in loading Dashboard "+error);
     });
  }

  handleOnSubmit = () => {
     console.log("submittwed");
     axios({
       method:'post',
       url:'http://localhost:3000/authenticate',
       data: {
         email: 'test@mail.com',
         password: 'apple'
       },
     })
      .then(function (response) {
        var token = response.data.auth_token;
        console.log(token);
        this.loadDashboard(token);
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log("Error in login "+error);
      });
   }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
         Username: <input type="email" name="fname" /><br />
         Password: <input type="password" name="lname" /><br />
         <button onClick={this.handleOnSubmit}>LOG IN</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Login;
```

**NOTE:** Without `loadDashboard`, `handleOnSubmit` function works just fine.

**Also**, why changing `loadDashboard(token){..}` to `function loadDashboard(token){..}` gives me `Unexpected token` error?

Comment: `this.loadDashboard = this.loadDashboard.bind(this);` to `this.loadDashboard = loadDashboard.bind(this);`

Comment: "Also, why changing loadDashboard(token){..} to function loadDashboard(token){..} gives me Unexpected token error? " in objects, the `foo() {}` syntax is the shorthand for  `foo: function() {}` therefor you don't have to use the `function` keyword in classes

Comment: @Nocebo doing that gives `'loadDashboard' is not defined  no-undef` in compilation. And the program halts.

Comment: you could do the this binding also for the handleOnSubmit method. `handleOnSubmit () {}` and in the constructor simliar to the laodDashboard: `this.handleOnSubmit = this.handleOnSubmit.bind(this)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you could use the arrow function to have the correct `this` context in your callback:

```
.then((response) => {
    var token = response.data.auth_token;
    console.log(token);
    this.loadDashboard(token);
  })
```

You could also do something like this, but `arrow` function are way smoother:

```
axios.get("/yourURL").then(function(response) {
  this.setState({ events: response.data });
}.bind(this));
```

Comment: Your solution worked. Thanks. I was following Axios official docs. They have used `function (response){..}` type of syntax [here](https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios#example). **Also** can you please explain why that approach was wrong?

Comment: @mwCoder As the answer already briefly stated, if you use `function ()` and try to access `this` within this callback `this` now refers to the callback function itself and not to the context of your component. You basically loose the context of `this` if you don't use `arrow functions`

Comment: you could probably look some online material regarding the arrow function and the lexical 'this' context. i give it a try. when you use the `function` keyword, then the function can accept a `this` context, namely with `.call()` or `apply()` axios propably does that.you could though generate a function which has a fixed context with `.bind(yourThisContext)` but when you use the arrow function, the `this` is the value of the enclosing execution context .

Answer (score 3):

The smoothest way is to use `arrow` functions whenever you define a function:

```
loadDashboard = (token) => {//Note the arrow function
    axios({
      method:'get',
      url:'http://localhost:3000/api/dashboard',
      data: {
        Authorization: token
      },
      responseType:'stream'
    })
     .then((response) => { //Note the arrow function
       console.log(response);
     })
     .catch((error) => {//Note the arrow function
       console.log("Error in loading Dashboard "+error);
     });
  }
```

This way you don't need to bind your functions in your constructor and don't loose the context of `this`.